# How can I maintian historical details from many table's information schema and account info?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to be able to extract the schema and account information for historical purposes for minimum of 10 years planning.

This is what I am using for selecting the query history, I would like to make a task to save it to a table.

```html
Create TABLE TEMP_history(Query_id varchar, query_text varchar, database_name varchar, schema_name varchar, query_type varchar, Username varchar, role_name varchar, warehouse_name varchar, execution_status varchar, start_time timestamp, End_time timestamp); 
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(select Query_id, query_text, database_name, schema_name, query_type, Username, role_name, warehouse_name, execution_status, start_time, End_time from table("TEMP_DB"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA".query_history())
order by start_time);
```

I want to do something like this:

```html
CREATE OR Replace TASK test_history
   WAREHOUSE = 'TEST_xx'
   SCHEDULE = '58 Minutes'
AS
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(select Query_id, query_text, database_name, schema_name, query_type, Username, role_name, warehouse_name, execution_status, start_time, End_time from table("TEMP_DB"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA".query_history())
order by start_time);
```

Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Are you running into issues?  If so, what is the issue?

Comment: Looks like you're on the right path, but if you're an ACCOUNTADMIN you could get the same information from the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema.  From which you could load your local table on a more or less frequent schedule without the missing records based on the limit within the table function.

Comment: The error message is "SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by taking a different direction and rewriting the task for once a day instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code, I ran it and recommend these two changes:

Change the type of the start_time and end_time in your temp_table to: 
timestamp_ltz

The error, what is the error you are getting?